# NIST test vectors for RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function?

Tags: encryption, pkcs1

I haven't been able to find it on the web anywhere, and I need to check if my implementation of the algorithm is correct. Does NIST provide such a file?

Answer (score 3):

A zip file of test vectors ([FIPS 186-2 Algoithm Test Vectors for RSA](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/dss/186-2rsatestvectors.zip)) can be found at the bottom of the page on NIST's site pertaining to [CAVP Testing: Digital Signatures](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/digital-signatures.html#rsavs).

This file contains a readme and the test vectors for X9.31RSA,  RSA PKCS#1 Ver 1.5, and RSA PKCS#1 RSASSA-PSS signature generation. It looks like it does contain vectors for SHA-256.